# Reassigning global variable in JavaScript - Can somebody explain to me why currentAcc stays undefined

Tags: javascript, function, dom, event-handling, variable-assignment

so basically I tried the same thing in a simple test scenario without .addEventlistener() and it works but I do not get this to work, **currentAcc** stays undefined in the global scope and does not takes the assigned value of the function. I would much appreciate some help.

````
let currentAcc;

function logIn() {
  function logInCurrAcc(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    currentAcc = accounts.find((acc) => acc.username === usernameInput.value);
    console.log(currentAcc);

    if (currentAcc.password === passwordInput.value) {
      window.location.assign("app.html");
    } else {
      alert.classList.remove("hidden");
      setTimeout(function () {
        alert.classList.add("hidden");
      }, 3000);
    }
  }

  submitFormBtn.addEventListener("click", logInCurrAcc);
}

console.log(currentAcc);

// Initializes everything
function init() {
  if (document.body.contains(tabsContainer)) {
    tabsComponent();
    sliderComponent();
    modal();
    logIn();
  } else {
    console.log("Not loading init");
  }
}

init();```
````

Comment: The top-level `console.log(currentAcc)` is being executed before the user clicks the login button.

Comment: You should get a correct log inside the `logInCurrAcc()` function.

Comment: that means I generally cant use the variable outside because everything will execute before the button is pushed ? I want to use this outside of the function ` welcomeMessage.textContent = `Welcome back, ${currentAcc.owner}`;`

Comment: Of course you can use global variables. For instance, you can read the variable in another event listener. If they click on button A then button B, B can show the value that was set by A.

Comment: You're trying to print the username when the page is loaded, not after they login.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand what you said. I think the main problem is because I switch with  `window.location.assign("app.html")` to another html file, then even when I try to use it with another even listener, it wont work anymore. How would I fix that?

Comment: Variables are all reset when you reload the page. Use `localStorage` to pass data between pages.

Comment: Did not know that, now it makes sense. I tried with localStorage it works with a string. I guess to safe and retrieve an object, I need to serialize with JSON.stringify. Thank you again, saved my night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript interpreter doesn't enter the body of a function until it gets executed.

This is a simplified example of how the interpreter executes your code:

```js
let currentAcc; // empty variable declaration

function logIn() {} // function declaration, doesn't enter, only saves a pointer to it into the memory

console.log(currentAcc) // undefined, because `currentAcc` is still empty

function init() {} // function declaration

init() // function execution, now interpreter goes into the body of `init` func and so on
```

So according to the code you posted, `currentAcc` variable stays `undefined` until user click.

If you need to pass data between pages, consider using [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or
[window.sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

If you need more help, please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so I can help you with some actual code.

Comment: Thanks, that clarified it even better. Did not notice that variables are reseted when refreshing. But the localStorage tip was a game changer. I fixed it with that and JSON.stringify and JSON PARSE. Now i have the object outside of the function and can work with it. Thanks again.